# What is best way and minimal code to check empty with default value in asp.net web api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the best way with minimum code written to check if incoming object is null for all HTTP action like Post, Put.

For example

```
public long Post(Category category)
    {
        try
        {
            Service.UpdateCategory(category);
            return category.id;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            ErrorLog.WriteLog(Config._SystemName, this.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, error.ToString());
            return 0;
        }
    }
public long Put(Category category)
    {
        try
        {
            long category_id = Service.CreateCategory(category);
            return category_id;
        }

        catch (Exception error)
        {
            ErrorLog.WriteLog(Config._SystemName, this.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, error.ToString());
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

imagine I have a lot of controllers, and I do not want to code one by one, I was thinking of using abstract but every put and post is different in every controller. is there any free AOP or interceptor or intelligent way to write little code but achieving the expected result. I am a bit lazy here :).

Comment: well, if you're using the default model binder, I don't think `category` will ever be null

Comment: Yes, you are right. thanks. it can be all values are either default type value. but what is the way to achieve writing little code but check all controller

Comment: do you have validation on `Category`? Can you check the `ModelState`?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make it clear, it actually is WebApi